# How to make the input and return types of functions unrelated in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

The anyelement type in PGSQL must be bound to a return value. My project has a large amount of MySQL code, and it is now preparing to adapt to the PGSQL database. I am currently working on function adaptation, and I want to adapt to the 'FROM_UNIXTIME' function in MySQL. However, I encountered the following problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."from_unixtime"("indate" anyelement, "informate" text)
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."timestamp" AS $BODY$
BEGIN

    IF upper($2) = upper('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') THEN
        return to_timestamp($1)::TIMESTAMP;
    END IF;

    IF upper($2) = upper('%Y-%m-%d') THEN
        return to_date(to_char(to_timestamp($1),'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD');
    END IF;
        
    IF upper($2) = upper('%H:%i') THEN
        return to_char(to_timestamp($1),'HH24:MI');
    END IF;
        
    IF upper($2) = upper('%H:%i:%s') THEN
        return to_char(to_timestamp($1),'HH24:MI:SS');
    END IF;
    -- ..... more
    raise exception 'undefined:% ',$2;
    return null;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

PASS:

```
-- pass
SELECT from_unixtime(1234567890, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), pg_typeof(from_unixtime(1234567890, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'));
```

ERROR:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(1234567890, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), pg_typeof(from_unixtime(1234567890, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'));
```

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "23:31:30"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function from_unixtime(anyelement,text) while casting return value to function's return type
```

I try define another function, such as from_unixtime_str, from_unixtime_date，but i have to modify my project's sql, it's to large

Comment: I don't understand. How can you expect a function that returns a `timestamp` to return a `text`?

Comment: Whenever you `return something_` from this function, it tries to `cast(something_ as "pg_catalog"."timestamp")` because that's what you defined as the return type. If that's your attempt at a polymorphic function, there's [a doc section on the topic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC).

Comment: Your function return type is timestamp, which holds BOTH a date and a time e.g. '2004-10-19 10:23:54'. Your error occurs when you pass the second argument "informate" as '%H:%i:%s', because your function uses to_char to form a string which is ONLY THE TIME "23:31:30", and attempts to convert this to a timestamp which fails because there is no date information. So your function definition doesn't make any sense, because you cannot have a timestamp which only contains time and not date.

Comment: I fail to understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you `return something_` from this function, it tries to `cast(something_ as "pg_catalog"."timestamp")` because that's what you defined as the return type. Therefore, it's not possible for these two cases to produce a valid output:

```
    IF upper($2) = upper('%H:%i') THEN
        return to_char(to_timestamp($1),'HH24:MI');
    END IF;
        
    IF upper($2) = upper('%H:%i:%s') THEN
        return to_char(to_timestamp($1),'HH24:MI:SS');
```

because the resulting text is not enough to build the `timestamp`-type result - it's missing the year, month and date.

This one works fine, because given only a valid date as `timestamp` input, midnight is assumed as the time:

```
    IF upper($2) = upper('%Y-%m-%d') THEN
        return to_date(to_char(to_timestamp($1),'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD');
    END IF;
```

If that's your attempt at a polymorphic function, there's [a doc section on the topic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC).